# How to normalize the following tables to 3NF

Tags: database-normalization

So far I have the following tables:

```
Hotel (ID(pk), NoOfRooms, Phone, Address)
Room (No(pk), HotelID(pk), Rate, Size, Occupied, Loc)
Customer (Num(pk), SSN, Name, CreditCard, Address, StartDate, EndDate, AmtOwing, RoomNo(fk))
CareTaker (ID(pk), HotelID(fk), Name, Address, Phone, Email, Salary)
Manager (ID(pk), HotelID(fk), Name, Address, Phone, Email, Salary)
```

With the following assumptions:

Each manager can manage more than one hotel but a hotel may have only one manager

Each customer can only stay at one hotel and be given one room

Each caretaker works at only one hotel but a hotel may have many caretakers

Rooms in a particular hotel are unique but may not be unique across several branches of the hotels

Based upon the above assumptions I think there should be the following changes to the tables

```
Hotel (ID(pk), NoOfRooms, Phone, Address)
Room (No(pk), HotelID(pk), Rate, Size, Occupied, Loc)
Customer (Num(pk), Name, StartDate, EndDate, RoomNo(fk), SSN(fk))
CustomerPaymentInfo (SSN(pk), CreditCard, Address, AmtOwing)
CareTaker (ID(pk), HotelID(fk))
Manager (ID(pk), HotelID(fk))
Employee (ID(pk), Name, Address, Phone, Email, Salary)
```

Let me know what you think and if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each manager can manage more than one hotel but a hotel may have only one Manager

=> So you need a manager per hotel, not one hotel per manager

- Hotel (ID(pk), **ManagerID(fk)**, NoOfRooms, Phone, Address)
- Manager (ID(pk), **REMOVE THIS: HotelID(fk)**, Name, Address, Phone, Email, Salary)

Rooms in a particular hotel are unique but may not be unique across several branches of the hotels

=> okay

- Room (No(pk), HotelID(pk), Rate, Size, Occupied, Loc)

Each customer can only stay at one hotel and be given one room

=> A room is identified by room number plus Hotel:

- Customer (Num(pk), SSN, Name, CreditCard, Address, StartDate, EndDate, AmtOwing, RoomNo(fk), **HotelID(fk)**)

Each caretaker works at only one hotel but a hotel may have many caretakers

=> okay

- CareTaker (ID(pk), HotelID(fk), Name, Address, Phone, Email, Salary)

Comment: Do you think that there should be a separate employee table and a separate payment info or are those not needed?

Comment: That depends. Yes, a manager and a caretaker are both employees. The question is: Will there be processes where you would like to have them both in one table? Will there be more kinds of employees in the future? As it is, it is fine. But if one day you have ten kinds of employees and local phone numbers shall be internationalized you will have to update ten tables instead of one employee table. If it is decided to allow for longer addresses you will have to alter ten tables. But well, maybe these things never happen.

Comment: As to the separate payment info it's about the same. So far you only have a salary amount. That's usually not worth a table of its own. But salary + provision + currency might. Or a salary history. Or a raise effective in the future. It really depends. There is nothing wrong with the data model, but you may want separate tables for future processes. But this also makes things a bit more complicated. How to guarantee for instance that there is a salary record for every employee?